# Laptop turns on but nothing shows up on screen (black screen)

Tags: vga, black-screen-of-death

I let my laptop on sleep mode, battery on, and let it cool down using a fan. When I got back, I turned it on, but there was no loggon screen. black screen and everything else is working (caps lights, hard drive, fan...). I turned it off but then again same issue. 
I have gateway laptop M series with Core dual 1.00 ghz, 4g ram, 2g ati 3200hd vga. 
what could be the problem? I tried reseting the memory, holding power for 60s (ps: the power button sometime get jammed and it's difficullt to do the 60s reset thing).

Comment: I would try to take the hard drive out and boot to bios. See if something changes. I had the same thing happen to me last night and I took the hard drive out, nothing changed. So I unplugged the power and held the power button for 10 sec and plugged it back in. Then I was able to get to bios, so I plugged my hard rive back in. Thats all it took.

Comment: I usually pulled the battery out and then did the reset.

Comment: I've tried doing the reset option countless times but nothing changes, but I didnt do it removing the hd drive. will try and see the result

Answer (score 0):

1. boot into Safe Mode
2. open Device Manager via "devmgmt.msc" in a run box
3. click on any item in the device list then click on "View">"Show hidden devices"
4. if you see any with yellow triangles or exclamation points, right click and select "Uninstall" (make sure "delete driver" is unchecked)
5. Reboot and reboot again when prompted (if this worked)

If this does not work try an automatic repair from the recovery console or perform an offline SFC from the recovery console command prompt.

Comment: I can't access win7 or bios screen to do this. my laptop turns on but stay stuck before the bios screen.

Comment: You said you tried reseting the memory, did you try taking one stick out and switching to see if you have a faulty memory module?

Comment: Yes, i did try it. Still the same issue. Should i try reseting bios memory?

Comment: Try pulling your CMOS battery, laptop battery and power cord and hold the power button down for 60 seconds, kind of like what you did before but with the CMOS / BIOS battery disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

if possible try using any other video output such as the VGA output, if this doesn't work your graphics adapter is buggered and you either:

need to get it fixed at a computer shop (they will probably send it off to the manufacturer or order a replacement motherboard) or you can just buy a new laptop.

Comment: Thanks. I happen to have none integrated vga in my gateway laptop. Should i replace it?

Comment: I would consider replacing it, ive seen this problem many times.